# Mongoose converting & to &amp;

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose storing & as `&amp;`

I have a schema in mongoose, I'm inserting data in the collection using save method code below

```
// Schema
var userSchema = new Schema({
 payLoad: []
})

// in controller code
var userJson = {
payLoad: [JSON.stringify(req.body)]
}
var User = require('../models/userModel')
new User(userJson).save().then(function (res) {


})
```

It's storing data in collection but when & is present it'c converting to & for example if payload has data Brothers & Sons then in mongodb it's storing Brothers `&amp;` Sons

Comment: Are you *sure* it's Mongoose doing that?! I find it more likely that `req.body` already contains `&amp;`.

Comment: yes, It's Mongoose doing that.

Comment: You have verified this how? Is it reproducible with a simple `new User({ payLoad: [{ foo: '&bar' }] }).save()`?

Comment: I have turned debug on for Mongoose, and it's showing in my terminal and payload inside model.insertOne(), in insertOne method it's passing &amp;

Comment: So before the .save(), it says '&' and then in the debug log of mongoose it says '&amp'?

Comment: I have print model json in mongoose pre save userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var model = this
  console.log('model',model)
}) Here printing &amp; and when mongoose inserting data in DB it's inserting &amp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue I was using one node module called require('mongoose-sanitizer') it is replacing & to `&amp;`